# Block and Wait for Asynchronous Operations in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

When I want to get userID from Facebook, I need to wait the API "startWithCompletionHandler" to send me back the userID, then I continue my task. Just like the code listed below.

But I can not use dispatch_semaphore or dispatch_group to wait for the api to callback. Except for completionHandler, any other solution like "blockAndWait" in MagicalRecord that can help me solve question like this?

Also, the solution listed below isn't working. It seems blocked the main thread, so it'll keep logging "WAITING" and can not pop up the Facebook login view.

```
-(void)getAccountIDAndWait{
__block BOOL isFinish = NO;
[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *aUser, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"bug in getAccountIDAndWait");
         return;
     }

     self.accountID = [aUser objectForKey:@"id"];
     isFinish = YES;
 }];

while(isFinish==NO){
    sleep(0.1);
    NSLog(@"WAITING");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what Chuck said I've slightly modified your code to allow the `getAccountIdAndWait` function to finish (and thus the main thread to idle) and when the completionHandler is called it will call the `doTheNextThing` function.

```
-(void)getAccountIDAndWait{
    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *aUser, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"bug in getAccountIDAndWait");
            return;
        }

        self.accountID = [aUser objectForKey:@"id"];
        [self doTheNextThing];
    }];

}
```

Comment: Will this cause a retain cycle if you access self inside a block?

Comment: But what I want is wait for completionHandler to be completed and then doTheNextThing. Any way I can do that?

Comment: @VenkatS.Rao accessing self inside of a block does not necessarily imply that you have a retain cycle. That is only the case if the block is also retained by self (directly or indirectly).

Comment: Allen Lin, how is what I've written not doing what you're asking? The last line of the completionHandler calls doTheNextThing so it happens after all the statements in the completionHandler have been run. And no, you can't have the runloop suspended in a function waiting for something without blocking that run loop.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are using there *is* blocking. As you correctly observe, this is not really what you want. The design intent here is for you to put things that you want to happen after the request completes in the completion handler.